# Using eles.breadthFirstSearch() to perform operations on nodes it traverses

Tags: cytoscape.js

Can eles.breadthFirstSearch() be used to perform operations on the nodes it traverses over?
From the documentation:

```
eles.breadthFirstSearch( [function(i, depth)] [, directed] )
function(i, depth) A handler function that is called when a node is visited in the search.
– i The index indicating this node is the ith visited node.
– depth How many edge hops away this node is from the root nodes.
directed A boolean indicating whether the search should only go along edges from source to target (default true).
```

It looks like the callback function is only given the index and the depth.

If this isn't the right function, is there another which works better?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the "this" environment variable contains the current node

Comment: It's the same for all traversing functions, just like jQuery